# jQuery hotkeys plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Using this hotkeys plugin, https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys, I'm having some problems with the following code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    function insert_tag(tag){
        $('#water_chemistry').val($('#water_chemistry').val()+' ['+tag+'] ');
    }

    $(document).bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+1', insert_tag("temp_min"));
    $(document).bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+2', insert_tag("temp_max"));
    $(document).bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+3', insert_tag("pH_min"));
    $(document).bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+4', insert_tag("pH_max"));
    $(document).bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+5', insert_tag("hardness_min"));
    $(document).bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+6', insert_tag("hardness_max"));
    $(document).bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+7', insert_tag("conductivity_min"));
    $(document).bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+8', insert_tag("conductivity_max"));

    $('a#temp_min').click(insert_tag("temp_min"));
    $('a#temp_max').click(insert_tag("temp_max"));
    $('a#pH_min').click(insert_tag("pH_min"));
    $('a#pH_max').click(insert_tag("pH_max"));
    $('a#hardness_min').click(insert_tag("hardness_min"));
    $('a#hardness_max').click(insert_tag("hardness_max"));
    $('a#conductivity_min').click(insert_tag("conductivity_min"));
    $('a#conductivity_max').click(insert_tag("conductivity_max"));

});
```

If I refresh the page, all of the tags are inserted into the textarea.

I'm presuming I've messed my syntax up, but I'm not sure how!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off:

```
$('a#hardness_max').click(insert_tag("hardness_max")); 
// is equivalent to:
var tmp = insert_tag("hardness_max");
$('a#hardness_max').click(tmp); // this calls the click handler with the result of the insert_tag function
```

What you probably wanted was:

```
$('a#hardness_max').click(function() { insert_tag("hardness_max"); }); 
// This function registers the click callback
```

As for the `ctr+alt+1`, it is the same case, but I would also add the textbox so they can do the shortcut in the textbox:

```
$(document).add('#water_chemistry').bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+1', function() { insert_tag("temp_min"); });
```

---

So the final result is:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    function insert_tag(tag){
        $('#water_chemistry').val($('#water_chemistry').val()+' ['+tag+'] ');
    }

    var docAndTextarea = $(document).add('#water_chemistry');

    docAndTextarea.bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+1', function() { insert_tag("temp_min"); });
    docAndTextarea.bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+2', function() { insert_tag("temp_max"); });
    docAndTextarea.bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+3', function() { insert_tag("pH_min"); });
    docAndTextarea.bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+4', function() { insert_tag("pH_max"); });
    docAndTextarea.bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+5', function() { insert_tag("hardness_min"); });
    docAndTextarea.bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+6', function() { insert_tag("hardness_max"); });
    docAndTextarea.bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+7', function() { insert_tag("conductivity_min"); });
    docAndTextarea.bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+8', function() { insert_tag("conductivity_max"); });

    $('a#temp_min').click(function() { insert_tag("temp_min"); });
    $('a#temp_max').click(function() { insert_tag("temp_max"); });
    $('a#pH_min').click(function() { insert_tag("pH_min"); });
    $('a#pH_max').click(function() { insert_tag("pH_max"); });
    $('a#hardness_min').click(function() { insert_tag("hardness_min"); });
    $('a#hardness_max').click(function() { insert_tag("hardness_max"); });
    $('a#conductivity_min').click(function() { insert_tag("conductivity_min"); });
    $('a#conductivity_max').click(function() { insert_tag("conductivity_max"); });

});
```

---

**And here is the jsFiddle:**

[FIDDLE!](http://jsfiddle.net/DmP2Q/)

Comment: Ahhh, I knew it was some daft syntax problem. That's working a treat now - thank you ever so much Bob.

Comment: Funny thing, when I use the jsfiddle, the textarea gets filled by all tags when I click on any keyboard button.